# Integration Unity 3D AR into Android Studio - Duplicate Classes

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, gradle, integration

For a few weeks I have tried to integrate my AR 3D Unity project into Android Studio.
I have come across this error several times:

:app:processDebugMainManifest
:app:checkDebugDuplicateClasses
:app:mergeDebugNativeLibs

the log error for :app:mergeDebugNativeLibs is the following ( i had to delete hundreds of lines in this same duplicate class situation):

```
> Task :app:mergeDebugNativeLibs FAILED

FAILURE: Build completed with 3 failures.

1: Task failed with an exception.
-----------
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugMainManifest'.
> Manifest merger failed with multiple errors, see logs

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
==============================================================================

2: Task failed with an exception.
-----------
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:checkDebugDuplicateClasses'.
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.CheckDuplicatesRunnable
   > Duplicate class android.support.v4.app.RemoteActionCompatParcelizer found in modules core-1.12.0-runtime (androidx.core:core:1.12.0) and jetified-androidx.core.core-1.2.0-runtime (:androidx.core.core-1.2.0:)
    
     Duplicate class androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider$AndroidViewModelFactory found in modules jetified-androidx.lifecycle.lifecycle-viewmodel-2.0.0-runtime (:androidx.lifecycle.lifecycle-viewmodel-2.0.0:) and lifecycle-viewmodel-2.7.0-rc02-runtime (androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel:2.7.0-rc02)
     Duplicate class androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider$Factory found in modules jetified-androidx.lifecycle.lifecycle-viewmodel-2.0.0-runtime (:androidx.lifecycle.lifecycle-viewmodel-2.0.0:) and lifecycle-viewmodel-2.7.0-rc02-runtime (androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel:2.7.0-rc02)
     Duplicate class androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider$NewInstanceFactory found in modules jetified-androidx.lifecycle.lifecycle-viewmodel-2.0.0-runtime (:androidx.lifecycle.lifecycle-viewmodel-2.0.0:) and lifecycle-viewmodel-2.7.0-rc02-runtime (androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel:2.7.0-rc02)
     Duplicate class androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelStore found in modules jetified-androidx.lifecycle.lifecycle-viewmodel-2.0.0-runtime (:androidx.lifecycle.lifecycle-viewmodel-2.0.0:) and lifecycle-viewmodel-2.7.0-rc02-runtime (androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel:2.7.0-rc02)
     Duplicate class androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelStoreOwner found in modules jetified-androidx.lifecycle.lifecycle-viewmodel-2.0.0-runtime (:androidx.lifecycle.lifecycle-viewmodel-2.0.0:) and lifecycle-viewmodel-2.7.0-rc02-runtime (androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel:2.7.0-rc02)
     Duplicate class androidx.loader.app.LoaderManager found in modules jetified-androidx.loader.loader-1.0.0-runtime (:androidx.loader.loader-1.0.0:) and loader-1.0.0-runtime (androidx.loader:loader:1.0.0)
     Duplicate class androidx.loader.app.LoaderManager$LoaderCallbacks found in modules jetified-androidx.loader.loader-1.0.0-runtime (:androidx.loader.loader-1.0.0:) and loader-1.0.0-runtime (androidx.loader:loader:1.0.0)
     Duplicate class androidx.loader.app.LoaderManagerImpl found in modules jetified-androidx.loader.loader-1.0.0-runtime (:androidx.loader.loader-1.0.0:) and loader-1.0.0-runtime (androidx.loader:loader:1.0.0)
     Duplicate class androidx.loader.app.LoaderManagerImpl$LoaderInfo found in modules jetified-androidx.loader.loader-1.0.0-runtime (:androidx.loader.loader-1.0.0:) and loader-1.0.0-runtime (androidx.loader:loader:1.0.0)
     Duplicate class androidx.loader.app.LoaderManagerImpl$LoaderObserver found in modules jetified-androidx.loader.loader-1.0.0-runtime (:androidx.loader.loader-1.0.0:) and loader-1.0.0-runtime (androidx.loader:loader:1.0.0)
     Duplicate class androidx.loader.app.LoaderManagerImpl$LoaderViewModel found in modules jetified-androidx.loader.loader-1.0.0-runtime (:androidx.loader.loader-1.0.0:) and loader-1.0.0-runtime (androidx.loader:loader:1.0.0)
     Duplicate class androidx.loader.app.LoaderManagerImpl$LoaderViewModel$1 found in modules jetified-androidx.loader.loader-1.0.0-runtime (:androidx.loader.loader-1.0.0:) and loader-1.0.0-runtime (androidx.loader:loader:1.0.0)
     Duplicate class androidx.loader.content.AsyncTaskLoader found in modules jetified-androidx.loader.loader-1.0.0-runtime (:androidx.loader.loader-1.0.0:) and loader-1.0.0-runtime (androidx.loader:loader:1.0.0)
     Duplicate class androidx.loader.content.AsyncTaskLoader$LoadTask found in modules jetified-androidx.loader.loader-1.0.0-runtime (:androidx.loader.loader-1.0.0:) and loader-1.0.0-runtime (androidx.loader:loader:1.0.0)
     Duplicate class androidx.loader.content.CursorLoader found in modules jetified-androidx.loader.loader-1.0.0-runtime (:androidx.loader.loader-1.0.0:) and loader-1.0.0-runtime (androidx.loader:loader:1.0.0)
     Duplicate class androidx.loader.content.Loader found in modules jetified-androidx.loader.loader-1.0.0-runtime (:androidx.loader.loader-1.0.0:) and loader-1.0.0-runtime (androidx.loader:loader:1.0.0)
     Duplicate class androidx.loader.content.Loader$ForceLoadContentObserver found in modules jetified-androidx.loader.loader-1.0.0-runtime (:androidx.loader.loader-1.0.0:) and loader-1.0.0-runtime (androidx.loader:loader:1.0.0)
     Duplicate class androidx.loader.content.Loader$OnLoadCanceledListener found in modules jetified-androidx.loader.loader-1.0.0-runtime (:androidx.loader.loader-1.0.0:) and loader-1.0.0-runtime (androidx.loader:loader:1.0.0)
     Duplicate class androidx.loader.content.Loader$OnLoadCompleteListener found in modules jetified-androidx.loader.loader-1.0.0-runtime (:androidx.loader.loader-1.0.0:) and loader-1.0.0-runtime (androidx.loader:loader:1.0.0)
     Duplicate class androidx.loader.content.ModernAsyncTask found in modules jetified-androidx.loader.loader-1.0.0-runtime (:androidx.loader.loader-1.0.0:) and loader-1.0.0-runtime (androidx.loader:loader:1.0.0)
     Duplicate class androidx.loader.content.ModernAsyncTask$1 found in modules jetified-androidx.loader.loader-1.0.0-runtime (:androidx.loader.loader-1.0.0:) and loader-1.0.0-runtime (androidx.loader:loader:1.0.0)
     Duplicate class androidx.loader.content.ModernAsyncTask$2 found in modules jetified-androidx.loader.loader-1.0.0-runtime (:androidx.loader.loader-1.0.0:) and loader-1.0.0-runtime (androidx.loader:loader:1.0.0)
     Duplicate class androidx.loader.content.ModernAsyncTask$3 found in modules jetified-androidx.loader.loader-1.0.0-runtime (:androidx.loader.loader-1.0.0:) and loader-1.0.0-runtime (androidx.loader:loader:1.0.0)
     Duplicate class androidx.loader.content.ModernAsyncTask$4 found in modules jetified-androidx.loader.loader-1.0.0-runtime (:androidx.loader.loader-1.0.0:) and loader-1.0.0-runtime (androidx.loader:loader:1.0.0)
     Duplicate class androidx.loader.content.ModernAsyncTask$AsyncTaskResult found in modules jetified-androidx.loader.loader-1.0.0-runtime (:androidx.loader.loader-1.0.0:) and loader-1.0.0-runtime (androidx.loader:loader:1.0.0)
     Duplicate class androidx.loader.content.ModernAsyncTask$InternalHandler found in modules jetified-androidx.loader.loader-1.0.0-runtime (:androidx.loader.loader-1.0.0:) and loader-1.0.0-runtime (androidx.loader:loader:1.0.0)
     Duplicate class androidx.loader.content.ModernAsyncTask$Status found in modules jetified-androidx.loader.loader-1.0.0-runtime (:androidx.loader.loader-1.0.0:) and loader-1.0.0-runtime (androidx.loader:loader:1.0.0)
     Duplicate class androidx.loader.content.ModernAsyncTask$WorkerRunnable found in modules jervices-basement-17.3.0:) and jetified-play-services-basement-18.1.0-runtime (com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:18.1.0)
     Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.common.annotation.KeepForSdkWithMembers found in modules jetified-com.google.android.gms.play-services-basement-17.3.0-runtime (:com.google.android.gms.play-services-basement-17.3.0:) and jetified-play-services-basement-18.1.0-runtime (com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:18.1.0)
     Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.common.annotation.KeepName found in modules jetified-com.google.android.gms.play-services-basement-17.3.0-runtime (:com.google.android.gms.play-services-basement-17.3.0:) and jetified-play-services-basement-18.1.0-runtime (com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:18.1.0)
     Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.common.annotation.NonNullApi found in modules jetified-com.google.android.gms.play-services-basement-17.3.0-runtime (:com.google.android.gms.play-services-basement-17.3.0:) and jetified-play-services-basement-18.1.0-runtime (com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:18.1.0)
     Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.common.api.Api found in modules jetified-com.google.android.gms.play-services-base-17.3.0-runtime (:com.google.android.gms.play-services-base-17.3.0:) and jetified-play-services-base-18.1.0-runtime (com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:18.1.0)
     Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.common.api.Api$AbstractClientBuilder found in modules jetified-com.google.android.gms.play-services-base-17.3.0-runtime (:com.google.android.gms.play-services-base-17.3.0:) and jetified-play-services-base-18.1.0-runtime (com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:18.1.0)
     Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.common.api.Api$AnyClient found in modules jetified-com.google.android.gms.play-services-base-17.3.0-runtime (:com.google.android.gms.play-services-base-17.3.0:) and jetified-play-services-base-18.1.0-runtime (com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:18.1.0)
     Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.common.api.Api$AnyClientKey found in modules jetified-com.google.android.gms.play-services-base-17.3.0-runtime (:com.google.android.gms.play-services-base-17.3.0:) and jetified-play-services-base-18.1.0-runtime (com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:18.1.0)
     Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.common.api.Api$ApiOptions found in modules jetified-com.google.android.gms.play-services-base-17.3.0-runtime (:com.google.android.gms.play-services-base-17.3.0:) and jetified-play-services-base-18.1.0-runtime (com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:18.1.0)
     Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.common.api.Api$ApiOptions$HasAccountOptions found in modules jetified-com.google.android.gms.play-services-base-17.3.0-runtime (:com.google.android.gms.play-services-base-17.3.0:) and jetified-play-services-base-18.1.0-runtime (com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:18.1.0)
     Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.common.api.Api$ApiOptions$HasGoogleSignInAccountOptions found in modules jetified-com.google.android.gms.play-services-base-17.3.0-runtime (:com.google.android.gms.play-services-base-17.3.0:) and jetified-play-services-base-18.1.0-runtime (com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:18.1.0)
     Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.common.api.Api$ApiOptions$HasOptions found in modules jetified-com.google.android.gms.play-services-base-17.3.0-runtime (:com.google.android.gms.play-services-base-17.3.0:) and jetified-play-services-base-18.1.0-runtime (com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:18.1.0)
     Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.common.api.Api$ClientKey found in modules jetified-com.google.android.gms.play-services-base-17.3.0-runtime (:com.google.android.gms.play-services-base-17.3.0:) and jetified-play-services-base-18.1.0-runtime (com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:18.1.0)
     Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.common.api.ApiException found in modules jetified-com.google.android.gms.play-services-basement-17.3.0-runtime (:com.google.android.gms.play-services-basement-17.3.0:) and jetified-play-services-basement-18.1.0-runtime (com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:18.1.0)
     Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.common.api.AvailabilityException found in modules jetified-com.google.android.gms.play-services-base-17.3.0-runtime (:com.google.android.gms.play-services-base-17.3.0:) and jetified-play-services-base-18.1.0-runtime (com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:18.1.0)
     Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.common.api.Batch found in modules jetified-com.google.android.gms.play-services-base-17.3.0-runtime (:com.google.android.gms.play-services-base-17.3.0:) and jetified-play-services-base-18.1.0-runtime (com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:18.1.0)
     Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.common.api.Batch$Builder found in modules jetified-com.google.android.gms.play-services-base-17.3.0-runtime (:com.google.android.gms.play-services-base-17.3.0:) and jetified-play-services-base-18.1.0-runtime (com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:18.1.0)
     Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.common.api.BatchResult found in modules jetified-com.google.android.gms.play-services-base-17.3.0-runtime (:com.google.android.gms.play-services-base-17.3.0:) and jetified-play-services-base-18.1.0-runtime (com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:18.1.0)
     Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.common.api.BatchResultToken found in modules jetified-com.google.android.gms.play-services-base-17.3.0-runtime (:com.google.android.gms.play-services-base-17.3.0:) and jetified-play-services-base-18.1.0-runtime (com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:18.1.0)
     Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.common.api.BooleanResult found in modules jetified-com.google.android.gms.play-services-base-17.3.0-runtime (:com.google.android.gms.play-services-base-17.3.0:) and jetified-play-services-base-18.1.0-runtime (com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:18.1.0)
     Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.common.api.CommonStatusCodes found in modules jetified-com.google.android.gms.play-services-basement-17.3.0-runtime (:com.google.android.gms.play-services-basement-17.3.0:) and jetified-play-services-basement-18.1.0-runtime (com.google.android.gms:play-mon.api.Response found in modules jetified-com.google.android.gms.play-services-basement-17.3.0-runtime (:com.google.android.gms.play-services-basement-17.3.0:) and jetified-play-services-basement-18.1.0-runtime (com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:18.1.0)
     Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.common.api.Result found in modules jetified-com.google.android.gms.play-services-basement-17.3.0-runtime (:com.google.android.gms.play-services-basement-17.3.0:) and jetified-play-services-basement-18.1.0-runtime (com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:18.1.0)
     Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.common.api.ResultCallback found in modules jetified-com.google.android.gms.play-services-basement-17.3.0-runtime (:com.google.android.gms.play-services-basement-17.3.0:) and jetified-play-services-basement-18.1.0-runtime (com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:18.1.0)
     Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.common.api.ResultCallbacks found in modules jetified-com.google.android.gms.play-services-basement-17.3.0-runtime (:com.google.android.gms.play-services-basement-17.3.0:) and jetified-play-services-basement-18.1.0-runtime (com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:18.1.0)
     Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.common.api.ResultTransform found in modules jetified-com.google.android.gms.play-services-base-17.3.0-runtime (:com.google.android.gms.play-services-base-17.3.0:) and jetified-play-services-base-18.1.0-runtime (com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:18.1.0)
     Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.common.api.Scope found in modules jetified-com.google.android.gms.play-services-basement-17.3.0-runtime (:com.google.android.gms.play-services-basement-17.3.0:) and jetified-play-services-basement-18.1.0-runtime (com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:18.1.0)
     Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.common.api.Status found in modules jetified-com.google.android.gms.play-services-basement-17.3.0-runtime (:com.google.android.gms.play-services-basement-17.3.0:) and jetified-play-services-basement-18.1.0-runtime (com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:18.1.0)
    com.google.android.gms.play-services-tasks-17.1.0-runtime (:com.google.android.gms.play-services-tasks-17.1.0:) and jetified-play-services-tasks-18.0.2-runtime (com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks:18.0.2)
     Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.tasks.DuplicateTaskCompletionException found in modules jetified-com.google.android.gms.play-services-tasks-17.1.0-runtime (:com.google.android.gms.play-services-tasks-17.1.0:) and jetified-play-services-tasks-18.0.2-runtime (com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks:18.0.2)
     Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnCanceledListener found in modules jetified-com.google.android.gms.play-services-tasks-17.1.0-runtime (:com.google.android.gms.play-services-tasks-17.1.0:) and jetified-play-services-tasks-18.0.2-runtime (com.google.android.gms:play-services-task
     Duplicate class com.google.vr.dynamite.client.b found in modules jetified-arcore_client-runtime (:arcore_client:) and jetified-core-1.41.0-runtime (com.google.ar:core:1.41.0)
     Duplicate class com.google.vr.dynamite.client.c found in modules jetified-arcore_client-runtime (:arcore_client:) and jetified-core-1.41.0-runtime (com.google.ar:core:1.41.0)
     Duplicate class com.google.vr.dynamite.client.d found in modules jetified-arcore_client-runtime (:arcore_client:) and jetified-core-1.41.0-runtime (com.google.ar:core:1.41.0)
     Duplicate class com.google.vr.dynamite.client.e found in modules jetified-arcore_client-runtime (:arcore_client:) and jetified-core-1.41.0-runtime (com.google.ar:core:1.41.0)
     Duplicate class com.google.vr.dynamite.client.f found in modules jetified-arcore_client-runtime (:arcore_client:) and jetified-core-1.41.0-runtime (com.google.ar:core:1.41.0)
     
     Go to the documentation to learn how to <a href="d.android.com/r/tools/classpath-sync-errors">Fix dependency resolution errors</a>.

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
==============================================================================

3: Task failed with an exception.
-----------
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugNativeLibs'.
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.MergeNativeLibsTask$MergeNativeLibsTaskWorkAction
   > 2 files found with path 'lib/arm64-v8a/libarcore_sdk_c.so' from inputs:
      - C:\Users\rmf-m\.gradle\caches\transforms-3\3482baeee4f8cab88b1f3ce824dd7a2d\transformed\jetified-core-1.41.0\jni\arm64-v8a\libarcore_sdk_c.so
      - C:\Users\rmf-m\.gradle\caches\transforms-3\304d5f2da44835dceb2cbf05b826f74d\transformed\jetified-arcore_client\jni\arm64-v8a\libarcore_sdk_c.so
     If you are using jniLibs and CMake IMPORTED targets, see
     https://developer.android.com/r/tools/jniLibs-vs-imported-targets

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
==============================================================================

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 4s
51 actionable tasks: 15 executed, 36 up-to-date
```

I tried to change gradle versions according to this [text](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/android-gradle-overview.html) page but no luck.

I am trying to do this integration following exactly this Unity documentation [text](https://docs.unity3d.com/2023.2/Documentation/Manual/UnityasaLibrary-Android.html).
In this git you can follow exactly how to do so:[text](https://github.com/Unity-Technologies/uaal-example/blob/master/docs/android.md)
I had no problems until building the project.